# how to turn on GPS in Android?

Tags: android, gps, maps

I am writing an application related to location. Nevertheless, I need to turn on the GPS in case it is off before other functions can process. I have searched but I did not see any way to auto turn on GPS. How to start this functionality by coding ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [start Android gps service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498075/start-android-gps-service)

Comment: you can't 'auto turn on' however you can present a dialog that directs the user to the option to turn it on